# some questions on battery

Tags: electricity

Need some help with very basic questions on battery.

1. my understanding of working of battery is that due to redox reactions, electrons move from one end of terminal to another in a circuit. Is this correct .?
2. If #1 is correct. does chemical reaction happen when you connect the battery to circuit or it keeps happening while battery is not in circuit and keeps on builiding one terminal +ve and other -ve.?
3. the current that flows in circuit when you connect a battery to a circuit. Is it due to elctrons from battery, or from conductor or both.?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. my understanding of working of battery is that due to redox reactions, electrons move from one end of terminal to another in a circuit. Is this correct .?

Correct

> 2. If #1 is correct. does chemical reaction happen when you connect the battery to circuit or it keeps happening while battery is not in circuit and keeps on builiding one terminal +ve and other -ve.?

The redox operation in a battery is actually voltage dependent.  When you put the components for the battery together, theoretically the voltage between the terminals is 0.  At that point, the redox equation goes into full tilt, generating electrons at the negative terminal and letting positive ions flow to the positive terminal.  As it does this, it builds up an electrical potential between the terminals (the 1.5V of a AA battery).  As the voltage goes up, the redox reaction slows down, until at 1.5V, the redox equation stops, perfectly in balance with the voltage between the terminals.

When you start using the battery, the movement of electrons to power your circuit causes the voltage to dip (slightly... not very much), and that causes the redox equation to spring back to life, striving to maintain that 1.5V equilibrium.

> 3. the current that flows in circuit when you connect a battery to a circuit. Is it due to elctrons from battery, or from conductor or both.?

**Mu**.  That's the term in Buddhism used to answer a question which should be unasked, because any answer give can only lead to suffering.  Simply don't think in terms of "whose electrons are these."  Just don't.  The current is caused by the flow of electrons or other charged particles.  Full stop.

Okay, if you insist.  Electrons do actually flow from the negative terminal of the battery towards the positive terminal.  However, you can't ignore the electrons flowing from the wires in your circuit towards the positive side of the battery.  It is there they combine with the positively charged ions from the reactions in the battery to neutralize their charge.  If they didn't do this, then the voltage across the battery wouldn't be able to drop, permitting the redox equation to go forward.  Some of the electrons would indeed escape into the circuit, but not many.  Soon you would hit the limit: if there's no extra electrons at the negative terminal, and there's enough positive ions hanging out near the positive terminal to create 1.5V between the terminals, then the redox equation will halt until the circuit sends some electrons to the positive terminal.

So don't worry about whose electrons are causing things to flow.  Just treat it as a flow.  This will also help when you get to AC, where you'll see peculiar things like the ability to power circuits while the electrons almost stay still, vibrating in place!

Comment: @ Cort Ammon thx  so much. cleared lot of mud :) one more q. how do we explain bettery charging capacitor.? how doesn battery make one plate +ve and other -ve .?

Comment: To explain capacitors, you need to think about the electric field, not just the electrons themselves.  Consider a AA battery connected to a capacitor.  We know that the voltage within each wire is the same as any other point on that wire.  We know that the battery is creating a potential difference of 1.5V, so therefore the capacitor must also have 1.5V across that.  As a result, you end up with more electrons on the negative side of the capacitor, and fewer on the top side (capacitors themselves always have a net charge of 0, so postives and negatives equal out)

Comment: Some of those electrons that have to flee the positive side will go combine with ions in the battery to make up for the electrons that got moved to the capacitor by the electric fields generated by the electrons themselves!  Eventually this process will stop when you have enough electrons on one side of the capacitor (and protons/lack-of-electrons on the other side) to generate exactly 1.5V of electric field across the capacitor, balancing what the battery is doing.